# Can i access the output of the Entity Framework fluent api from within T4? - and can i extend it?

Tags: entity-framework, t4

I am using T4 templates to scaffold large part of my application from my model.

I am considering ways of annotating my model to indicate different types of UI implementation i want to support the relationship between different entities in the model.

It strikes me that i am already creating most of the metadata i require while i am using the EF fluent API to describe my relationships.

So can i access this data from within my T4 template?

And if i can access this data, is it possible to extend the EF fluent API to add additional metadata?

Answer (score 1):

If you look a the PowerTools project in http://entityframework.codeplex.com you can see their Mapping.tt. From it you can see how they access the mapping information from the connected database. This Mapping.tt is also used in http://trackable.codeplex.com. But both these have the benefit of an EFTextTemplateHost customisation, which also you can see the code in PowerTools.

In DbContext Fluent generator http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d663b99-ed3b-481d-b7bc-b947d2457e3c, you can open the VSIX and see his Mapping.tt, and they way he accesses the model's data.

And from the EntityFrameworks supplied include EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude you can see various classes to access the model.

Certiainly these are where I am looking for details of how to access EDMX data from within a T4 Template. And it is a nightmare!!